# Получить список файлов?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, доступ

Имеется сайт, на котором есть личный кабинет. Каждый пользователь может загружать файл (../upload) – txt файл (ранее список был виден для всех).
При переходе по адресу: **site.ru/upload**

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /upload/ on this server.
```

Но если указать прямой путь до файла (**site.ru/upload/file.txt**), то соответственно можно получить доступ. Таких файлов много, и они имеют разные названия (перебор по имени подошёл бы, но имена файлов могут быть и такими eq3wr23c23c.txt). В кэше гугла естественно нету этой страницы.
Может есть какой-нибудь способ получить список этих файлов?

Answer (score 1):

В папке **upload** нужно создать файл **.htaccess** и указать в нём `Options +Indexes`.